# Is there a vectorized approach for concatenation of this 2d lists than list comprehension?

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, concatenation

This is my sample code:

```
DF_LEN, COL_LEN, cols = 10, 5, ['A', 'B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O']
 
a = np.asarray(pd.DataFrame(1, index=range(DF_LEN), columns=cols))
a = list((map(lambda i: a[:i], range(1,a.shape[0]+1))))
  
b = np.asarray(pd.DataFrame(np.nan, index=range(DF_LEN), columns=cols))
b = list((map(lambda i: b[:i], range(1,b.shape[0]+1))))
b = b[::-1]

a_last   = a[-1];  del a[-1]
b_first  = b[0]; del  b[0]

a = [np.concatenate((x,y)) for x,y in zip(a,b)]
```

Its creating two lists of arrays of **varying sizes**, and then inverting the second and merging them, so that they have the same amount of sublists in each subarray.
To clarify my reproducable ecample:

```
a=[
   array([[1, 1, 1, 1]], 
                        dtype=int64), 
   array([[1, 1, 1, 1],  
          [1, 1, 1, 1]], 
                        dtype=int64), 
   array([[1, 1, 1, 1],  
          [1, 1, 1, 1],  
          [1, 1, 1, 1]], 
                        dtype=int64)]
b=[
   array([
       [nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, nan]
                            ]), 
   array([
       [nan, nan, nan, nan],
       [nan, nan, nan, nan]
                            ]), 
   array([
       [nan, nan, nan, nan]
                            ])
                                ]
res=[
      array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
             [nan, nan, nan, nan],
             [nan, nan, nan, nan],
             [nan, nan, nan, nan]
                                   ]), 

      array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
             [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
             [nan, nan, nan, nan],
             [nan, nan, nan, nan]
                                    ]), 
      array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
             [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
             [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
             [nan, nan, nan, nan]]
                                    )]
```

Is there a faster way than merging two lists of arrays of **varying sizes**, than this?

```
[np.concatenate((x,y)) for x,y in zip(a,b)]
```

EDIT:
or this:

```
np.array([npvstack((x,y)) for x,y in zip(a,b)])
```

EDIT:
Is there an approach without iterating? (vectorized)

Comment: Not the best practice in SO to duplicate post your questions, while you keep the previous ones open. You can always edit your previous questions and accept answers if you want to close them.

Comment: clicked on publish, when the vstack answer appeared i guess so thank you for your help ^^. I was just testing vstack and it works. -> Therefore i'll upvote and accept the answers in the other posts. I'd still look for the most efficient way to do this if thats possible.